# Strange SSL issue

Tags: html, ssl

I have purchased a Comodo positive SSL certificate few months ago and now I'm redesigning my website.

I'm facing a strange issue. When the link is loaded for first time Google Chrome warns me that the page includes unprotected resources that can be modified and change the website by a hacker. The strange issue is that after a page refresh the warning is not showing anymore and everything is as it should.

[HERE](https://gelasoft.com/GSNew/) is the link in question.

And here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
    <title>Gelasoft - Just like that</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="css/images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="css/font.css" type='text/css'>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-5.5.0-packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- shell -->
    <div class="shell">
        <!-- container -->
        <div class="container">
            <!-- header -->
            <header id="header">
                <h1 id="logo"><a href="#">Gelasoft</a></h1>
                <!-- search -->
                <div class="search">
                    <!-- MAYBE AN ADD HERE -->
                </div>
                <!-- end of search -->
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
            </header>
            <!-- end of header -->
            <!-- navigaation -->
            <nav id="navigation">
                <a href="#" class="nav-btn">HOME<span></span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">solutions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">jobs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
<!--                    <li><a href="#">contacts</a></li> -->
                </ul>
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
            </nav>
            <!-- end of navigation -->
            <!-- slider-holder -->
            <div class="slider-holder">

                <!-- slider -->
                <div class="slider">
                    <div class="socials">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Gelasoft" class="facebook-ico">facebook-ico</a>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/gelasoft" class="twitter-ico">twitter-ico</a>
                        <a href="skype:slim-style_bg?chat" class="skype-ico">skype-ico</a>
<!--                        <a href="#" class="rss-ico">rss-ico</a> -->
                        <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="arrs">
                        <a href="#" class="prev-arr"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="next-arr"></a>
                    </div>

                    <ul>
                        <li id="img1">
                            <div class="slide-cnt">
                                <h4>We can do it!</h4>
                                <h2>Just Like That</h2>
                                <p>Do you need a custom software? Do you need a logo design, business card, party cards, or flyers design? Maybe you need someone to convert your PSD to valid HTML? We do everything you have in your mind!<br> Just like that!</p>
                            </div>
                            <img src="css/images/mac-img.png" alt="" />
                        </li>

                        <li id="img2">
                            <div class="slide-cnt">
                                <h4>Heading Title Goes</h4>
                                <h2>Just Like That</h2>
                                <p>Acor porta mi, non venenatis augue imperdiet quis. Nam faucibus, felis ut suscipit vulputate, tortor quam ultricies neque, eget dignissim elit urna a metus. Aliquam sed quam dui, id lacinia nunc. <a href="#">read more</a></p>
                            </div>
                            <img src="css/images/mac-img.png" alt="" />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- end of slider -->

                <!-- thumbs -->
                <div id="thumbs-wrapper">
                    <div id="thumbs">
                        <a href="#img1" class="selected"><img src="css/images/thumb.png"/></a>
                        <a href="#img2"><img src="css/images/thumb2.png" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <a id="prev" href="#"></a>
                    <a id="next" href="#"></a>
                </div>
                <!-- end of thumbs -->
            </div>

            <!-- main -->
            <div class="main">

                <div class="featured">
                    <h4>Welcome to <strong>Gelasoft</strong>! Have a dream? We can realize it! Leave it to our <strong>professionals</strong>!</h4>
                    <a href="contactUs.html" class="blue-btn">GET IN TOUCH</a>
                </div>

                <section class="cols">
                    <div class="col">
                        <h3>About Us</h3>
                        <h5>Gelasoft is a software development organization</h5>
                        <p>Our main goal is to deliver quality services! We have a team always ready to spend time on your request. Every one of our customers is valuable and the most of them are returning back to us. We dare to say that our specialists are one of the best!! <br>Just like that!</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col">
                        <h3>We are Hiring</h3>
                        <img src="css/images/col-img.png" alt="" class="left"/>
                        <h5>Are you talented? Feel free to apply! </h5>
                        <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                        <p>We are always looking for talanted developers and designers! If you are one of them, feel free to submit your application in the form below. <br /><a href="getHired.html" class="more">Submit application</a></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col">
                        <h3>Our Services</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Web and desktop based solutions</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Design services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Business card printing</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                </section>

                <section class="entries">
                    <div class="entry">
                        <h3>Latest News</h3>
                        <div class="entry-inner">
                            <div class="date">
                                <strong>28</strong>
                                <span>2013</span>
                                <em>nov</em>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cnt">
                                <p>New design added! We hope that you will love it!</p>
                                <p class="meta">Just like that </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="entry">
                        <h3>Latest Project</h3>
                        <h5>Keep a track on our latest projects </h5>
                        <a href="#"><img src="css/images/col-img2.png" alt="" /></a>
                        <p>We are always working on something new! You can check our latest projects here  <br /><a href="#" class="more">check out</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="entry">
                        <h3>Testimonials</h3>

                        <div class="testimonials">                  
                            <p>Wow, I can say just that! My logo is amazing!</p>
                            <p class="author">Alexis D.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="testimonials">                  
                            <p>Thanks for fixing our forum issues!</p>
                            <p class="author">Alejandro H.</p>
                        </div>

                        <!--  
                        <div class="partners">
                            <h3>Our Partners</h3>
                            <img src="css/images/partners-img.png" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                </section>
            </div>
            <!-- end of main -->
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>

            <!-- footer -->
            <div id="footer">
                <div class="footer-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Solutions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <p class="copy">&copy; Copyright gelasoft 2012<span>| just like that</span></p>
                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <!-- end of footer -->
        </div>
        <!-- end of container -->
    </div>
    <!-- end of shell -->
</div>
<!-- end of wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

I have no external resources in my code. What can be causing the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your fonts (Raleway) are loading over HTTP. You need to go into your CSS file and change the src URLs so they are not "HTTP" in 'fonts.css'.

All the CSS, JS, and fonts loaded are considered "external resources," so your page indeed does have them.

**EDIT**: To check for this in Chrome in the future, open the developer tools under View->Developer->Developer Tools, and navigate to the "Console" tab. You may need to reload the page to see the specific errors, but they will look like this:

```
The page at 'https://gelasoft.com/GSNew/' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/raleway/v6/PKCRbVvRfd5n7BTjtGiFZBsxEYwM7FgeyaSgU71cLG0.woff': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```